# Is ε terminal in context-free?

Tags: automation, context-free-grammar, automata

```
R: S ---> aSb
   S ---> SS
   S ---> ε
```

How should I write the grammar for these expressions?

Is it true to writing like this?

```
G = ({S}, {a, b}, {S ---> aSb, S ---> SS, S ---> ε}, {S})
```

or like this (adding epsilon to terminals):

```
G = ({S}, {a, b, ε}, {S ---> aSb, S ---> SS, S ---> ε}, {S})
```

which is the correct one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ε is a way to make a zero- length sequence visible. It is not a grammar symbol.

The actual production is: `S →`   — that is, `S` can produce nothing — but the invisibility of nothing makes it hard to read. So we usually write ε, which is more legible. You should read it as nothing, though.

Comment: you mean ε is not the terminal in grammar, don't you?

Comment: @alkokura49: It is neither a terminal nor a non-terminal: it represents a *sequence* of grammar symbols, which happens to be empty. In the same way, `aSb` is neither a terminal nor a non-terminal: it is a sequence of three grammar symbols. ε is a sequence of zero symbols.